# oracle sql sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle

All,

I have a sql which is like below used in informatica lookup sql.

`select * from table where load_dt = trunc(sysdate)` when the time is 2 am to 00.00 am

when time is between nextday 00.30am to 2.00 am, the same sql should read as

```
select * from table where load_dt = trunc(sysdate-1)
```

how can i make these two sql in single sql?

is it possible?

thanks

Comment: use a case statement to evaluate the time which determines if you need to subtract  0 or 1 from sysdate. depending if you need to take into account regional offsets you could use extract or to_char() https://community.oracle.com/thread/2422420?tstart=0 to extract hour and check to see if it's less than 2

Comment: What should happen between next day 00:00 and 00:30?

Comment: loading of table starts at 2.00 am to 00.00 (running at every 30min). when load run between this duration (takes current day). when it runs between 00 to 2 am it takes next day and create duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question but I'm assuming that if the hour is less than 2 am you want to subtract 1 from sysdate otherwise keep current sysdate.

You said; 2 am to 00.00 am and 00.30am to 2.00 am... but I interpreted it as above.

```
Select * 
from table 
where load_Dt = trunc(sysdate - case 
   when TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24') < 2 then 1 else 0 end)
```

or

```
Select * 
from table 
where load_Dt = trunc(sysdate - case 
   when EXTRACT(HOUR FROM SYSTIMESTAMP) < 2 then 1 else 0 end
```

Depending if Timezone offset is needed or not.

Comment: I tried this sql and used TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP,'HH24')  to get Hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can just subtract two hours before truncating the date:

```
select *
from table
where load_dt = trunc(sysdate - 2/24.0) ;
```

Oracle also supports `- interval '2' hour`, but I'm old-fashioned sometimes.